# Problems in configure pgpool

Tags: pgpool

I have two Postgresql servers ha1 and ha2, and one Pgpool server for pooling connection, load balancing and to manage failover.
When I ran 'show pool_nodes' I saw:
node_id   hostname   status     role        pg_role      select_cnt
0         ha2        up         standby     unknown      750
1         ha1        up         standby     unkonow      176

There is load balancing as expected, by no primary node.
I ran pcp_promote_node  0
and then I ran 'show pool_nodes' again and I saw:
node_id   hostname   status     role        pg_role      select_cnt
0         ha2        up         primary     unknown      850
1         ha1        down       standby     unkonow      176

The first node became primary' but the second node status changed to down and I lost load balancing.

I stopped PG Service in ha2. No failover has done, and in failover.log I saw the message:
failover.sh: All nodes are down, skipping failover.

I restart PG in ha2, then I couldn't connect to the Pgpool server and I had to restart Pgpool.
After restarting I returned to the previous status, that both servers had status standby.
I think that I had a mistake in the definitions.
Any help would be appreciated.
Arie.